# How to convert characters of an Integer “1” to a string “One” into in swift

Tags: swift

I want converting int number in to letter of this number .I Have one text field .in this text field user can write number then i want convertin this number to letter  . for example i want convert 11 to eleven .how can i do this work in swift .

Comment: Hi Hadiseh, welcome to the site. Read the documentation of [`NumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter), it does what you're looking for, with `numberStyle` set to `.spellOut`

Comment: the opposite direction https://stackoverflow.com/a/46856525/2303865

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut
let english = formatter.string(from: 1)
```

and you can Refer this Awesome [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250433/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-the-corresponding-words-in-objective-c) for objective-c.

If you wanted to get that in Espanol , you would set a locale like this:

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
let spanish = formatter.string(from:1)
```

Comment: It won't be `English` unless implicit current `Locale` is `en_*`. So calling variable `english` is misleading.

Comment: Hi You can use your local, for example spanish like this : formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "es_ES")
let spanish = formatter.string(from: 1)

Comment: You have to change identifier for your local language , as i have edited the answer for example.